# How to set the field values in a form

Tags: magento-1.9, php, adminform

For Magento (1.9) how to set the value to the Magento form.

```
  $fieldset->addField('country_code', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Title3'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'country_code',
          'style'   => "border:10px",
          'value'  => 'hello !!',
          'disabled' => false,
          'readonly' => true,
        ));
```

I set the value is `hello !!` but it is not working.

[image]

Comment: try this `$data['{field_name}'] = 'your_value';`

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that values you set with `addField()` method are then overwritten with `addValues()` method which tries to set up a form fields values when form is used for editing existing entities or error occurred during submission.

Here is a workaround. Most likely you are getting values with a protected method like this:

```
protected function _getFormData()
{
    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData();

    if (!$data && Mage::registry('current_osmm_project')->getData()) {
        $data = Mage::registry('current_osmm_project')->getData();
    }

    return (array) $data;
}
```

So inside of your `_prepareForm()` method you replace:

```
$form->addValues($this->_getFormData());
```

with:

```
$_data = $this->__getFormData();
if (!empty($_data)) {
    $form->addValues($_data);
}
```